# How to locate the specified directory with powershell?

Tags: powershell, search, find, locate

Powershell installed on my debian8.
To locate the specified directory with bash.

```
sudo find /  -name  'vim74'
/usr/share/vim/vim74
```

Here is my try with powershell.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path /  -Filter 'vim74'
```

Nothing output,how to fix it ?

There are two problem for running

```
Get-ChildItem -Path / -Filter 'vim74' -Recurse
```

1.no permission
2.so many wrong path

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, `Get-ChildItem` will only search the directory you give it so you're not getting any results because there is no file/folder matching `vim74` in your root path `/`

You need to use the `-Recurse` parameter in order to also search subfolders like so:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path / -Filter 'vim74' -Recurse
```

To see what you can do with `Get-ChildItem` you can look at the help using:

```
Get-Help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
```

Comment: Based on your screenshot, the error occurs because you don't have permission to view the directory, not because the command is failing. If you don't wish to see these errors you can add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your command.

Comment: The command isn't what needs the permission, the account you run the command as needs the permission. I don't think giving permission to every folder is a viable solution though. To correct my previous comment if you don't wish to see these errors you can add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the the command.